# Analyzing of DataFrame's with specific substring in rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I've got Pandas DataFrame similar to this one:

```
Date        Name        Value
2018-02-11  AP1-C4-we2  223
2018-04-22  AP1-C4-dej  44
2018-04-22  AP1-C4-dej  443
2018-05-02  AP4-C2-oe0  992
2018-05-02  AP1-C6-we2  29
2018-05-03  AP4-B5-iiu  58
2018-05-03  AP4-B5-ffw  12
```

How can I sum values of name starting with the same substring (first two parts of name)? It should look like this:

```
Date        Name    Value  
2018-02-11  AP1-C4  223 
2018-04-22  AP1-C4  487
2018-05-02  AP4-C2  992
2018-05-02  AP1-C6  29
2018-05-03  AP4-B5  70
```

I don't know all of the values that appear in 'Name' (there's many more of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
df.Value.groupby([df.Date,df.Name.str.rsplit('-',n=1).str[0]]).sum().sort_values().reset_index()
```

Comment: And could you tell me how can I sort it by value?

Comment: @alqueen add sort_values

Comment: You can include ignore_index within sort_values; it negates the need for a reset_index

Answer (score 1):

`.groupby` Date and a index zero of string split of name where split occurs on a `-` followed by lowercase alpha and numeric

```
df.groupby ([df['Date'],df.Name.str.split('[\-](?=[a-z0-9]+)').str[0]]).agg(Value=('Value','sum')).reset_index()

         Date    Name  Value
0  2018-02-11  AP1-C4    223
1  2018-04-22  AP1-C4    487
2  2018-05-02  AP1-C6     29
3  2018-05-02  AP4-C2    992
4  2018-05-03  AP4-B5     70
```